# combining two dataframes into one new dataframe in a zig zag/zipper way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1 and df2, i want to create new data frame df3, such that the first record of df3 should be first record from df1, second record of df3 should be first record of df2. and it continues in the similar manner.

I tried many methods with pandas, but didn't get answer.

Is there any ways to achieve it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post there sample of `df1`, `df2` and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a column with incremental id (one with odd numbers and other with even numbers:

```
import numpy as np
df1['unique_id'] = np.arange(0, df1.shape[0]*2,2)
df2['unique_id'] = np.arange(1, df2.shape[0]*2,2)
```

and then append them and sort by this column:

```
df3 = df1.append(df2)
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['unique_id'])
```

after which you can drop the column you created:

```
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['unique_id'])
```

Comment: It worked. i was trying out with pandas series

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: @jade - please mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,3,4,6], 'B':['a1','b1','c1','d1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,4,6,1], 'B':['a2','b2','c2','d2']})

dfff = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,4):
    dfx = pd.concat([df1.iloc[i].T, df2.iloc[i].T])
    dfff = pd.concat([dfff, dfx])
    
    
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(kind='merge'))
```

Which gives

```
 A   B
0  3  a1
0  5  a2
1  3  b1
1  4  b2
2  4  c1
2  6  c2
3  6  d1
3  1  d2
```